# How to onResume properly

Tags: android, onclick, onresume, onpause

I've created a simple app that has two buttons that will play and stop a song. Everything is working as it should.

However I want it to pause the song when the app goes onPause and Resume playing the song when the app is up again.

I have tried:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mp.start();
}
```

But that starts the song automatically when the app starts the first time. And it also messes up the app when you click play, the song hacks and the app crashes.

Here is the onPause and onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    mp.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
} }
```

Comment: when do you think `onResume` will be called?

Comment: You have to manage this by flags only. Becuase OnResume will be called everytime when activity comes on foreground.

Comment: `onResume` will be called every time. Check if `mp == null` or `mp.isPlaying()` before saying `mp.start()`

Comment: @Raghunandan when the app is paused and then the app is back upp again, or what do you mean?

Comment: Ive already tried `@Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();
  if (mp != null) {
         mp.start();
         mp = null;
     }
 }` and mp.isPlaying() but it still starts the song when the app starts

Comment: @DroidShout after `onCreate` what will be called? onCreate -- > onStart --> onResume. read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. SO now you know why it tarts the song when the app starts.

Comment: @Raghunandan so how do I prevent it to start the song? But I want it to pause the song if I hit home button and then play it again when the app get back on foreground?

Comment: @DroidShout study lifecycle of activity and media player. You will find a way yourself. read the docs will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mp != null && mp.getCurrentPosition() > 0) {
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `onResume()` Method check if the song is already playing you shouldn't start it again.
So now your onResume becomes

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (mp != null && mp.getCurrentPosition() > 0) {
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

This will fix your crash.

Now for the second part, how do you resume playing from the position where it was paused.
As per the Documentation [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class has two method [`getCurrentPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition()) and `seekTo(int msec)` You can use `SharedPreferences` to store the currentPosition in `onPause()` Method and in your `onResume()` get the position for the `SharedPreferences` and [`seekTo(int msec)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) that position and then start playback again.

Comment: Did you try implementing the second part of my answer ?

Comment: The first part did not help, the second part did point me in the right direction. Thanks for your answer, i'll give it an upvote.